# application focus of emacsclient frame

Tags: emacs

I use emacs24 and I usually start emacs as a daemon at start then use emacsclient frames.

But I've encountered a problem: After I created the first frame, then whenever I created a new frame (after the first frame is closed) there would be a system message `"emacs24@myusername" is ready` popped out so that the new frame loses focus (the focus is on the message), which is rather annoying. It seems that it is because even if I close all frames some buffers are still open (like *Scratch* and *Messages*). I am just wondering if there is a way to prevent the system message from popping out?

Thanks!

EDIT: forgot to mention that I am using Gnome 3.

Answer (score 9):

Here is what I do :

```
(server-start)
(defun px-raise-frame-and-give-focus ()
  (when window-system
    (raise-frame)
    (x-focus-frame (selected-frame))
    (set-mouse-pixel-position (selected-frame) 4 4)
    ))
(add-hook 'server-switch-hook 'px-raise-frame-and-give-focus)
```

Comment: Thanks! This was really bothering me in Ubuntu 16.04 and I solved it with `/usr/bin/emacsclient -c -e "(progn (raise-frame) (x-focus-frame (selected-frame)))"`